# Even Functions, Symmetry, Inverse Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

Can someone explain why the answer is D

a < 0 because it finishes downwards
e < O because the y-intercept is in the negatives. 
b, & d = zero (but i don't get this)
c is supposedly > 0 (nor do i get this)

According to the solutions the graph is an even function, and symmetrical about the y-axis. I havent studied this, can someone please explain for values b,d,c.

Also explain terms even/odd function.

Answer (score 1):

A función $f$ is said to be even if for every $x$ in  its domain we have $f(x)=f(-x)$ and is said to be odd if $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Note hat we assume that $-x$ is also in the domain of $f$.
Now, define $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$. Since we want $f$ to be even, we should have $f(-x)= f(x)$ . Note that $f(-x)=ax^4-bx^3+cx^2-dx+e$. Then, we have
$$
ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=ax^4-bx^3+cx^2-dx+e
$$
And this implies that
$$
2bx^3+2dx=0
$$
For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Assuming the fundamental Theorem of Algebra, we know that if $b$ is different from zero, then the polynomial $2bx^3+2dx$ has at most three roots, but this is not the case since $2bx^3+2dx=0$ for more than three values of $x$ (since its zero for all of them). Then, $b=0$. We have then that $2dx=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$  so if $x\neq 0$ we can divide by $x$ and obtain $d=0$.
To see that $c>0$, suppose, to get a contradiction, that $c\leq 0$. But using that $x^4>0$ and $x^2>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we would have that $ax^4+cx^2+e<0$ because the sum of negative terms is again negative and  this contradicts that the graph contains points above the $x$-axis. Then, $c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is even, i.e., $f(-x)=f(x)$ (odd means that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ which yields rotational symmetry about the origin, which does not exist in this graph), which tells us that $b=d=0$ (the even powers take $-1\mapsto 1$, but the odd powers take $-1\mapsto-1$, so the odd powers must not exist to be even).  For large $|x|$, the dominating factor is the $ax^4$ (the largest power), which tells us based off of the graph that $a<0$.  For small $|x|$, the dominating factor is the $cx^2$, which tells us that $c>0$ (again based off the graph).  Finally, $e=f(0)<0$.

Comment: so this is what i got from the above:                         1. check to see if its even/odd by looking at the symmetry of the graph. if its even cancel out the odd powers.          2. then look at the largest power, and see where the y value is for that largest x value (so a will be negative).                          3. then look at the smallest power, but im confused how you can tell c>0 by looking at the graph.

Comment: For small $|x|$, the graph looks like a positive copy of $x^2$, so $c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

To see that $c>0$ notice that $f''(0) = 2c$ and that the function is convex near $x=0$.